# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined iwith react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I follow the react-redux tutorial and I try to display post. I get the post data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. it returns the response like this:

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPost } from '../actions'

class PostList extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }
    renderList(){
        return this.props.post.map(pos => {
            return (
                <div className="item" key={pos.id}>
                    <p>{pos.title}</p>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
    render(){
        return(<div className="ui relaxed divided list"> {this.renderList()} </div>);
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return { post:state.post}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps , { fetchPost })(PostList);
```

this is my action creater

```
import JsonPlaceHolder from '../apis/JsonPlaceHolder'
export const fetchPost = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const response = await JsonPlaceHolder.get('/posts');
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_POST',
            payload:response
        });
    }
};
```

this is my reducer

```
export default (state=[],action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "FETCH_POST":
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

this is my ../apis/JsonPlaceHolder file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
});
```

**but i get the error like this**

> TypeError: this.props.post.map is not a function

Comment: Please post `../apis/JsonPlaceHolder` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should check, whether you have `this.props.post` or not, before you map it, because request takes some time and during that process you could receive an `undefined` value from `this.props.post`.

Plus, if you want to map `this.props.post`, then you should return as payload not just `response`, but `response.data`. Otherwise, you'll get an error, that the object doesn't have a method `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract `data` from `response`.

```
dispatch({
  type: 'FETCH_POST',
  payload:response.data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract the data from response in

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return { post:state.post.data}
}
```